# How do I remove a server iTunes is complaining about?

Tags: itunes

Every time I launch iTunes I get this pop-up message:

```
iTunes can’t verify the identity of the server “www.EXAMPLE.com”.
```

I have no idea where that's from! I'm guessing it's maybe a podcast I added a long time ago? But I can't even see podcasts in the UI any more! (I'm on Version 12.9.5.5)

How do I find this so I can remove this and stop the pestering?

Comment: Is the site mzstatic.com?

Comment: No, it's something else.